# Checking if the variable is empty when using textarea

Tags: javascript

I thought that if the value !== null that an empty textarea would do nothing.

It seems in the console log that its printing an empty message. so the message is empty but my if statement isnt working propperly because its still taking action.

Anyone can help me out?

```
var newMessage = document.getElementById('newTicketMessage');
if(newMessage !== null){
   console.log(newMessage.value)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't checking the `value` with

```
if(newMessage !== null){
```

Use

```
if(newMessage.value !== null){
```

Or change

```
var newMessage = document.getElementById('newTicketMessage');
```

to

```
var newMessage = document.getElementById('newTicketMessage').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! eventually the code below did the trick for me because it still sended me an empty console message.

```
var newMessage = document.getElementById('newTicketMessage').value;
if(newMessage !== null && newMessage.length > 0){
    console.log(newMessage)
}
```